# GetComputerName() works on win7 but fails on xp

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp

I am trying to use GetComputerName() to retrieve the box's name. The code works great on windows 7, however, when i test on windows xp the code does not work (result is UNKNOWN). Any idea why?

```
int GetBoxName(BoxInfo &box_info)
{
    int Ret;    
    DWORD dwLen;
    const char* szUnk = "UNKNOWN\0";

    // Get the size of the box name then allocate memory.
    Ret = GetComputerName(NULL, &dwLen);
    box_info.BoxName = new char[dwLen]; 

    // Attempt to retrieve the box name.
    if((Ret = GetComputerName(box_info.BoxName, &dwLen) == 0))
    {       
        delete[] box_info.BoxName;
        box_info.BoxName = new char[strlen(szUnk)];
        box_info.BoxName = (char*)szUnk;
        return 1;       
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried calling GetLastError?

Comment: If you are using `wsprintf`, you should probably not use `char`?

Comment: @Mats: `wsprintfA` is the ASCII version of a Win32 API function.  Perhaps you are confusing it with the C wide string function `swprintf`?

Comment: Probably. Can't make any sense of any names of functions in MS libraries, can you?

Comment: @Mats: Actually, it's more regular than the CRT.  ASCII vs Unicode is always indicated by a `A` or `W` suffix, and the name without any suffix is forwarded to one of the real functions based on the `UNICODE` macro.

Comment: And the w at the beginning means "Windows"?

Comment: That's my guess as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ben has given a good account of errors that you made. I'd like to show you how you would typically call `GetComputerName`. You are making it harder than it needs to be. The key information is the excerpt from the documentation:

> The buffer size should be large enough to contain MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1 characters.

You have a hard upper bound on the size of the buffer. You can therefore use a fixed size buffer, and only make a single call to `GetComputerName`.

```
std::string getComputerName()
{
    char buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD len = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    if (GetComputerName(buffer, &len))
        return std::string(buffer, len);
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
```

Were you compiling for Unicode it would be:

```
std::wstring getComputerName()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD len = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    if (GetComputerName(buffer, &len))
        return std::wstring(buffer, len);
    return L"UNKNOWN";
}
```

If you want to cater for the possibility of the computer name being longer than `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` then you can write it like this:

```
std::string getComputerName()
{
    char buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD len = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    if (GetComputerName(buffer, &len))
    {
        return std::string(buffer, len);
    }
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    {
        std::vector<char> name(len);
        if (GetComputerName(&name[0], &len))
        {
            return std::string(&name[0], len);
        }
    }
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
```

I don't know whether or not this can even happen. The docs hint that it can, although if it does happen then it renders `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` somewhat of a misnomer. If we pass a value of `len` that is less than `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1` then the function succeeds if the name fits. It does not automatically fail with `ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`. Of course, if the name returned by this function can never exceed `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` then the second version is rather paranoid.

---

FWIW, the code in your updated answer is still badly broken. You simply must not pass `NULL` for the first parameter to `GetComputerName`. The documentation could not be much clearer.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that. I realized that the max size is defined by MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH. But if the computer name is less than 15 is't that a waste of memory?

Comment: No it is not. The memory is allocated on the stack. It's already been reserved and most likely already allocated. What's more, your code is broken, according to the docs. The docs tell you that you have to pass a buffer of length at least `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1`. You are going to have to allocate that memory somewhere. The code in my answer is the canonical way to use this type of function.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks very much.

Comment: @SnakeByte I've extended the code to allow for the paradox of computer names whose length are greater than `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH`

Comment: I feel so stupid haha. Thanks for clearing that up. Why would the computer name be bigger than what is allowed?

Comment: Perhaps the limit was increased at some point in the past and this ancient API is left suffering the back-compat consequences.

Comment: And one last question. If the computer name as UNICODE chars in it (they are 2 bytes) and i try to store it in a char will it cut some of the name off and cause problems? Should i just be using wchar_t instead of char to be on the safe side.

Comment: Personally I would always use the native Unicode Windows API. The code in my answer assumes the ANSI API and works correctly. You certainly cannot stuff a `wchar_t` into a `char`. That's like trying to put an int into a short. It won't necessarily fit.

Comment: That's what i thought. Just wanted to know your opinion on using Unicode API's.

Comment: @SnakeByte I never use ANSI APIs.

Comment: Better to use `std::string.resize(len)` rather than copying or creating the `char array`?

Comment: @Cant In older standards I think it is possible that a string's memory need not be contiguous.

Comment: NETBIOS names can't be Unicode, so there's no disadvantage to the ANSI API.

Comment: And surprisingly, `NULL` is documented as valid when passed to `GetComputerNameEx`, which this function should be a thin wrapper for...

Comment: The reason i was passing NULL for the first param is because i read somewhere that when you do that the size of the name is set to the size param. But i guess just easier to allocate the variable to MAX_COMMPUTERNAME_SIZE + 1.

Wish i could mark 2 as the answer because you both helped me to find the solution. Such a newb mistake, but i am glad that i made it because now i know the correct way. Many thanks!

Comment: @Ben For this particular function that may be the case. As a general rule, I would always use Unicode APIS and see no reason to deviate here.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense at all:

```
box_info.BoxName = new char[strlen(szUnk)];
box_info.BoxName = (char*)szUnk;
```

You allocate memory, then immediately lose track of it.  And you are directing a non-`const` pointer to a string literal.  And the amount of memory allocated here doesn't include space for the terminating NUL byte, so you would overrun the buffer.

Perhaps you wanted the second line to be

```
strcpy(box_info.BoxName, szUnk);
```

And why aren't you using a smart pointer to automatically deallocate the memory when needed, for example `std::string` or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` ?

---

Finally, the documentation says

> The buffer size should be large enough to contain `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1` characters.

That is a pretty plain requirement.  Makes you wonder the point of

> If the buffer is too small, the function fails and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`. The *lpnSize* parameter specifies the size of the buffer required, including the terminating null character.

This latter behavior appears to only be true for the Unicode version.  [Stanly Roark](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/stanley%20roark/) left a comment on the MSDN page that:

> The ANSI version does not return the required length
>
> I have to maintain an old application that uses ANSI.
>   I have noticed that, while the Unicode version returns the required buffer length, the ANSI version does not.

Comment: @SnakeByte: It could explain your crash, if you later try to `delete[] box_info.BoxName`.

Comment: @SnakeByte: But I found another issue as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt The ANSI version returns the length too. If you pass it a real buffer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ahh, so it presumably is not returning `ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` but `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` for the NULL pointer?

Comment: @Ben On my machine it was a seg fault